# wpf style trigger on dynamic path

Tags: wpf, binding, path, styles

In the following style, is there a way to make the Binding Path generic so that this style can be used by multiple consumers, each supplying a different binding path?

```
<Style x:Key="OptionalBackground"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataPresenter:CellValuePresenter}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource OptionalFieldCellPresenter}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                       Path=Record.DataItem.IsEditAllowed}"
                     Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ReadOnlyField}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Short answer, no this can't be done. You have several alternatives though depending on your scenario. In theory, how would you want to do this? What would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can derive from `Style` to create a shorthand notation that looks like this:

```
<local:BackgroundStyle
    x:Key="OptionalBackground"
    TargetType="{x:Type DataPresenter:CellValuePresenter}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource OptionalFieldCellPresenter}"
    Path="Record.DataItem.IsEditAllowed"
    Value="{StaticResource ReadOnlyField}"/>
```

and an implementation for this example might be:

```
public class BackgroundStyle : Style, ISupportInitialize
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public void BeginInit() { }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        var trigger = new DataTrigger
        {
            Binding = new Binding
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(Path),
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self)
            },
        };
        trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Value));
        Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }
}
```